# Pass a parameter to a CRM 2011 Workflow via the API

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have a workflow that has a 'Prompt and Response' dialogue. I can run the workflow from the API using `ExecuteWorkflowRequest` but how do I provide values for the prompt and response inputs?

Comment: I've revised my response. This doesn't look possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Workflows don't take parameters.

Dialogs take parameters, which are generally passed from other dialogs or queries.

The only thing I managed to do is to pass a related entity from parent workflow as the primary entity to a child workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to retract my earlier answer and upvote @Grigory instead.

See [this page from the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334463.aspx)

> **Note** Due to the interactive nature of the dialog process, you cannot run a dialog using the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK. A dialog can
>   only be run through the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web application and are
>   not supported in Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Microsoft Office Outlook
>   with Offline Access.

---

<strike>I don't know the answer, but I'd be fairly confident that this is:</strike>

- Possible
- Unsupported (as it is *not* documented in the SDK)

If *I* really needed to find out then I'd write a plugin to explore what happens when a workflow is fired internally (this makes an assumption that such a message is fired via the plugin pipeline - not necessarily a correct assumption).

I'd register this plugin on all stages of the `Execute` message (I assume) and then use debug logging or an interactive debug session (attached to the Async service) to examine the `InputParameters` (and maybe `OutputParameters` and `ExtensionData`) of the `ExecuteWorkflowRequest` that is (hopefully) generated when CRM runs a workflow that does have parameters. I expect that one of those PropertyBags will contain some sort of parameter.

Comment: I think the only noble bit is keeping my nonsense answer readily readable! ;) I'll put it down to not reading the question properly and barrelling in to quickly with an answer! :)