# C# call global action in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I have Global action in CRM. It have one input string parameter. 
This is call for sending request

```
obj.CallActivity("this is parameter string","MyActionName")
```

and my method *CallActivity* looks like this

```
public async Task<bool> CallActivity(string record, string Activity)
        {
           try
            {

                HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = null;
                requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, App.ResourceUri + "/api/data/v8.2/" + Activity); //uri to activity
                requestMessage.Content =new StringContent(record); 
                requestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
                //Send the HttpRequest
                Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
                  response.Wait();
                //If the response is Successfully executed then it will return the value true
                if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {

                return false;
            }
        }
```

When the executing the request, I get the message:

> StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:

Where I am making mistakes?

Comment: Could you please add the actual parameter values? The error is very likely in the way the string parameter `Activity` is built.

Comment: obj.CallActivity("{"id_contact":"452e368a-1783-e711-8102-70106faa95f1","id_car":"45436d5b-d19d-e711-8101-70106faa5221"}","MyActionName"). Input string parameter need to be like JSON string

Comment: I assume your "MyActionName" consists of a publisher prefix and your Action schema name, so this shouldn't be the issue. However you are not setting the O-Data version headers. I've seen the Web API throw a wobbly over this so you may want to try adding `"OData-MaxVersion", "4.0"` and `"OData-Version", "4.0"` headers.

Comment: On initialization class that have method  CallActivity I set          httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

Comment: You need to use SDK. Possible duplicate of [How to call Action with parameter(s) using ExecuteWorkflowRequest in Dynamics CRM 2016?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965325/how-to-call-action-with-parameters-using-executeworkflowrequest-in-dynamics-cr)

Comment: Is this being called from the CRM server or from an external application?

Comment: Yes, I call it from external application

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which I use to call my Action from Plugin.

**Sender** and **regardingcontact** are the two parameters for my Action and this works fine for me.

```
OrganizationRequest req = new OrganizationRequest("crmp_emailbenachrichtigunganeventowner468fcc7975b9e71180e6005056936953");

                        req["Sender"] = new EntityReference(temp.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("ownerid").LogicalName, temp.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("ownerid").Id);

                        req["regardingcontact"] = new EntityReference(context.PrimaryEntityName, context.PrimaryEntityId);
                        OrganizationResponse response = service.Execute(req);
```